# Datatables TableTools - Is it possible to only include the visible columns when saving CSV?

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I did some tests using the TableTools plugin for Datatables on saving CSV.

I noticed that it saves everything. It does not care if you filtered the rows nor if you hide some columns.

Is there a way to only save the data from visible columns?

Comment: First: Do you really want to use TableTools or just some CSV export? (I don't like the Flash part which is merely needed for clipboard access). Second: Do you want to export the visible rows on a dataTables paginated page or the whole filtered dataset? Third: Are you using local or serversided data? Finaly: Which version of dataTables are you using? (There was a large version change recently).

Comment: I really dont understand why you have two open questions on this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/23634595/1407478?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use the `mColumns` when defining your [buttons](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options).

An example from the documentation:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sButtonText": "Special columns",
                    "mColumns": [ 0, 1, 4 ]
                },
                {
                    "sExtends": "csv",
                    "sButtonText": "Visible columns",
                    "mColumns": "visible"
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

This defines two buttons that will export to a CSV file. The first one, labeled `Special columns`, will only exports columns `0,1,4`. The second button, labeled `Visible columns` will export all columns that are visible.

The `mColumns` parameter is described like this in the documentation:

> The parameter can either be a string with a value of 'all', 'visible',
>   'hidden' or 'sortable' - or an array of integers with the column
>   indexes to be exported.

This functionality is not new in the 1.10 version. It was also available in the [older version](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/button_options), if you have no yet upgraded.

Answer (score 5):

Just for completion... on the last version of DataTables, it's slightly different (here's the [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns.html)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
          {
              extend: 'print',
              exportOptions: {
                  columns: ':visible'
              }
          },
          'colvis'
      ],
      columnDefs: [ {
          targets: -1,
          visible: false
      } ]
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Datatables can be one of the most obtuse libraries with options that change names/syntax with every release  - I've been searching for this for a while; thanks for sharing!

Comment: Glad you found it useful! :)

Comment: This is the best answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a couple more options, which I needed for my scenario, which may be useful to someone.

Passing more than one parameter to columns, and using **not()** to exclude columns with a class:

```
extend: 'csv',                   
exportOptions: {
   columns: ':not(.noShow):visible'
}
```